# Separating numbers in a string to use in a calculation

Tags: python, string

I want to separate numbers in a string so I would be able to do a calculation with the numbers.

Example:

```
line_str = "23 22 55 67"
```

So far I have used:

```
for char in line_str:
print (char)
```

I don't know how to be able to make do a calculation with each number.

And I believe I can't just write `number_int = int(char)` and continue with `number_int`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What's the reason for down-voting all the below answers?

Comment: its like bonus -ve but y????

Answer (score -3):

```
>>> import re
>>> list(map(int, re.split(r'\s+', '23 22 55 67')))
[23, 22, 55, 67]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
line_str = "23 22 55 67".split(" ")
numbers = []
for n in line_str:
    numbers.append(int(n))

print numbers
```